# WebView : special link opened in external browser?

Tags: android, browser, webview

How can I change my code to open the link (https://mio.it) in the external browser? while the other links are fine if they open in the webview

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    intent = getIntent();
    sliderlink = intent.getStringExtra("sliderlink");
    Log.e("Data Received is", sliderlink);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    if (!sliderlink.startsWith("http://") && !sliderlink.startsWith("https://"))
        sliderlink = "https://" + sliderlink;

    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.loadUrl(sliderlink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a custom WebView client to your WebView. In that clied override shouldOverrideUrlLoading, this method will receive the URL that needs to be loaded.

Check if it matches https://mio.it and then return true else return false. Returning true will allow the system to launch the URL in any other application installed in the device while false will allow the WebView to keep loading the URL.

See the below Kotlin code:

```
        wv.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                if(url.contains("https://mio.it"))
                 return true
                return false
            }

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
              if(request.url.toString().contains("https://mio.it"))
                 return true
                return false
            }

        }
```